# Add a cxf provider into an abstract feature

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, cxfrs

I have written an abstract feature for cxfrs server to put all the interceptors and providers together.

```
public class RestInboundFeature extends AbstractFeature {  
        @Override
        protected void initializeProvider(InterceptorProvider provider, Bus bus) {    
        ProviderFactory providerFactory = ServerProviderFactory.getInstance();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JacksonJsonProvider jsonMessageWriter = new JacksonJsonProvider();
        jsonMessageWriter.setMapper(objectMapper);
        providerFactory.registerUserProvider(jsonMessageWriter);
    }
    }
```

And used the feature inside `<cxf:rsServer>` like this

```
<cxf:features>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.cxf.features.RestInboundFeature" />
</cxf:features>
```

But it doesn't work for providers. Later I put few interceptors in feature and they are working. Is this the wright way to add providers in abstract feature?